# General anaesthesia and brain cell damage

Tags: neurophysiology, human-physiology

Do we lose brain cells when we undergo prolonged surgery under general anaesthesia?

Comment: You are asking two distinct questions. You should decide which one you want answered.

Comment: These are conditions which can cause decreased oxygen supply to brain.I have asked so in that context.Want to know about both situations

Comment: Surgery, sneezing, strangulation. You ask a lot of anyone trying to research an answer. It's your question but I would vote to close as overly broad.

Comment: Okay .I understood.I just related these situations.Sorry for the inconvenience it created for answering

Comment: I think this question is fine now. The system won't let me change "loose" to "lose" or "anaesthesia" to "anesthesia." This would be an improvement...+1.